# Is it possible to embed vine video into an html email?

Tags: email, video, html-email, vine

I've found lots of instructions on how to embed vine video into web pages and blogs, but is it possible to embed it into emails?

I am aware this will almost certainly not work in older email clients but just wondered if it was even possible for the more modern applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I just looked at, it seems vine videos are embedded using an iframe and some javascript. 
Both of which are not supported in email clients. Old and new (At least in my experience).

My recommendation would be to host a page with your vine video embedded and design your email with a video poster and possibly a play button. That can then link to your hosted page with the vine video embedded.

Comment: That was my alternative idea too. Thanks

Comment: Or maybe make the vine into a gif? this will show in 8 out of 10 mail clients

Comment: Good call Rasmus. Animated GIFs are making quite a bit of headway in Email. Just remember that in clients that GIFs don't work, only the first frame of the GIF will display. Customize it to help your reader!